# compare two elements with jquery, change class based on result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get results from a database, insert that into an `<li>` and highlight the greater of the two values I get from those two HTML `<li>` elements.  I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zachs/syKWz/3/) but am unsure how to get `addClass()` to change the `<li>` based on the result of comparing the two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/syKWz/6/

**fixed**

- css class `li.leader`, invalid 7 digits color
- logic should add both `leader` & `follower` to compared pair `li`

**code**

```
$(function() {
    var val1 = parseInt($('.leader1').text(), 10);
    var val2 = parseInt($('.leader2').text(), 10);
    if(val1 > val2) {
        $('.leader1').addClass('leader'); 
        $('.leader2').addClass('follower');
    } else {
        $('.leader1').addClass('follower'); 
        $('.leader2').addClass('leader');
    }
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

```
$(function()
{
      var val1 = parseInt($('.leader1').text(), 10);
      var val2 = parseInt($('.leader2').text(), 10);
      if(val1 > val2){
        **$('.leader1').attr('class','.li.leader');** 
      }
      else{
            **$('.leader2').attr('class','.li.follower');**
      }
 }
 );
```

Comment: Interesting, would you mind pointing me to the documentation on those `**`?  I have not seen that before

Comment: Haha not sure if trolling or serious, but it was my way of showing the difference

Comment: Double troll!  I thought you were serious and vainly attempted to search for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample using the signature of `toggleClass` that accepts a function as argument.

```
$(function() {
    $("li").toggleClass(function() {
        if(parseInt($(this).text(), 10) >
           parseInt($(this).siblings().text(), 10)) {
               return "leader";
           } else {
               return "follower";
           }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function()
{
  var val1 = parseInt($('.leader1').text(), 10);
  var val2 = parseInt($('.leader2').text(), 10);
  if(val1 > val2){
    $('.leader1').addClass('leader'); 
  }
    else{
        $('.leader2').addClass('follower');
   }
}
```

);

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syKWz/5/